# NAN for date Python

Tags: python, date, isnan

I have a field that normally has a date value, and I would like to check if it's empty.

I've tried this:

```
np.isnan(row['date'] == True
```

However, this causes an error. This I used for string field. Is it different for each data type?

Comment: What is `row` a pandas dataframe or are you iterating over a frame?

Comment: You can just use `np.isnan(row['date'])`. There is no need for the `== True`

Comment: I am iterating over a frame. I am using this in a function. So i want to check if a date row is empty to give it a different value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), do not iterate

```
# set up a sample frame
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-15'), columns=['Date'])
# change some values to null
df.iloc[::4] = np.nan

# boolean indexing to find all null values
df_null = df[df['Date'].isna()]

   Date
0   NaT
4   NaT
8   NaT
12  NaT
```

Comment: Thanks! I get now the null values.
How do I use it in an if statement? If I use it than I get the error: The truth value of a dataframe is ambiguous. I need to learn a lot.

Comment: @Datawoman you do not need to use an if statement if you want to assign values to nulls. If you want to assign values based on a condition use numpy.select, numpy.where or df.where. If you want to assign a value to all nulls you can also use `df['Date'].fillna()`

Comment: Thanks, I wil try it.

Comment: It worked by the way! thanks

Answer (score 0):

NAN stands for Not A Number, which is not appropriate for dates. It seems that checking for null is a better approach.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am new to python :)

Comment: How do I check for null?